# Handle no connection case in curlGetResponse_

Tags: haskell, curl

Is there a way or special `curl` option to recognize a no-connection-situation when `curlGetResponse_` is used?

For example, there is some `curl`-command:

```
withCurlDo $ respBody <$> (curlGetResponse_ "google.com" [CurlFailOnError True] ∷ IO (CurlResponse_ [(String, String)] ByteString))
```

If there is a connection to host, it returns some `IO ByteString`.

But if there is no any connection, it takes 40 seconds and returns empty string.

Is there a way to throw and exception or some `Left` value, when connection is lost and host is unreachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set appropriate timeout with [ConnectTimeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/curl/1.3.7/doc/html/Network-Curl-Opts.html#v%3aCurlConnectTimeout) option and then check [response code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/curl/1.3.7/doc/html/Network-Curl.html#v%3arespCurlCode) for timeout errors:

```
μ> withCurlDo $ respCurlCode <$> (curlGetResponse_ "google.com" [CurlConnectTimeout 1] ∷ IO (CurlResponse_ [(String, String)] String))
CurlOK
μ> withCurlDo $ respCurlCode <$> (curlGetResponse_ "2.2.2.2" [CurlConnectTimeout 1] ∷ IO (CurlResponse_ [(String, String)] String))
CurlOperationTimeout
```

Comment: So, for no-connection situation there is a `CurlCouldntResolveHost` value. Thanks.